# Translatepress taxonomy and custom post type root FIX

Tags: url-rewriting, htaccess, translation

I'm using Translatepress. Great plugin, one exception: they haven't developed translation for taxonomies and custom post type root slugs.

Does anyone know how to achieve this? Some .htaccess magic rewrite rule?

Example:
- I have the page "domain.com/birds/eagle"
- The current translated page is "domain.com/es/birds/aguila"
- The goal is for the translated page to be "domain.com/es/pajaros/aguila"

Any geniuses out there?
Thanks!

Comment: Your example mean that there is another page. I dont think this can be done. You can detect if the URL contains `es` and redirect it to correct page.

Comment: There is not another page. "birds" is a custom post type and CPTs have their own root slug associated. That's exactly what I want to modify in the URL. And redirection is not a solution. I need a Rewrite so the page stays but the URL changes.

Comment: They just did https://translatepress.com/translate-categories-custom-taxonomies-in-wordpress/